# Duplicating items in a list with combinations

Tags: python, python-itertools

With two lists in Python:

```
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
j = [1, 4]
```

I'm trying to duplicate values in j and to get all unique combinations.
`i` can be a list of any (hashable) values. It will never contain duplicates, but the order of the values is important. `j` is always a subset of `i`. Integers are used for example only, the actual values could be strings.

The output should be:

```
[
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], # i is always included as a combination - this can be added independently if required
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
]
```

An additional example for clarity:

```py
i = ["B", "E", "C", "A", "D"]
j = ["C", "A", "D"]

# desired output - the order of i should be preserved
# but the order of lists within the outer list is unimportant
[
["B", "E", "C", "A", "D"], # original list
["B", "E", "C", "C", "A", "D"], # duplicated C
["B", "E", "C", "C", "A", "A", "D"], # duplicated C, A
["B", "E", "C", "C", "A", "D", "D"], # duplicated C, D
["B", "E", "C", "C", "A", "A", "D", "D"], # duplicated C, A, D
["B", "E", "C", "A", "A", "D"], # duplicated A
["B", "E", "E", "C", "A", "A", "D", "D"], # duplicated A, D
["B", "E", "C", "A", "D", "D"], # duplicated D
]
```

I've tried various list comprehension methods, and a few itertools functions such as product and combination, but have yet to find a satisfactory solution.

Half-working attempt is as follows, although it is an ugly approach:

```py
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
j = [1, 4]

all_lists = [i]
for x in j:
    new_list = i.copy()
    new_list.insert(i.index(x), x)
    all_lists.append(new_list)

print(all_lists)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]]
# still missing the [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4] case
```

Background to question - `i` is a list of nodes in a networkx network, and `j` a list of nodes with self-loops. The result is a combination of all non-simple paths between the nodes.

Comment: Is `i` guaranteed be sorted?  And `j`? Will both always contain no duplicates? For example, do we know we can never have `i= [1, 2, 2,3]`?

Comment: `i` will never contain duplicates, but there is no sorting, I used integers for the example, so i could also be `["D", "B", "A"]` and `j` `["B"]`

Comment: Can you explain why your example always has `i` completely contained but not `j`?

Comment: @dawg - it is one of the required combinations. It would be fine to simply add `i` to the output at the start or end as a separate operation.

Comment: @geographika just start with `all_lists = [i, list(sorted(i+j))]` then you can do `for item in j: all_lists.append(list(sorted(i + [item])))` ? (i.e. also add the `i + j` case manually, then do the combination with the items from the `j` list)

Comment: On your 2nd example, you have `duplicated C, D` twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to try to use `itertools`. The `combinations` function is what you want. Just loop over all possible lengths (from 0 to len(j)):

```
import itertools

i = ["B", "E", "C", "A", "D"]
j = ["C", "A", "D"]

result = []
for l in range(len(j) + 1):
    for j_subset in itertools.combinations(j, l):
        result.append(sorted(i + list(j_subset), key=lambda x: i.index(x)))


print(result)
```

You said that the lists can contain elements of any type. Here is an example of doing the same thing using a custom class `Node`:

```
import itertools

# here is my custom Node class
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

# the names of the nodes
names_i = ["B", "E", "C", "A", "D"]
names_j = ["C", "A", "D"]


# the actual data we are working with - lists of distinct nodes
i = [Node(name) for name in names_i]
j = [Node(name) for name in names_j]

result = []

for l in range(len(j) + 1):
    for j_subset in itertools.combinations(j, l):
        result.append(sorted(i + list(j_subset), key=lambda x: i.index([node for node in i if node == x][0])))


# print the raw result
print(result)

# print the result but just showing the node names
print([[node.name for node in result_element] for result_element in result])
```

The key difference with using classes is that two Node classes instantiated with the same name are not the same object, so `i.index(x)` in your `sorted` key will not work, since no elements of `j` are in `i` (even though they have the same name, and are "equal"). I can explain this more if you like.

Comment: `range(len(j) + 1)` is actually the right pick because the zero combination will give the missing original list

Comment: By the way I had the impression `j` was a list of indexes and not values

Comment: Thanks @JBernardo. I don't think j is indexes, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @PeacefulJames - thanks for this - a nice answer. Apologies for seemingly changing the criteria and not being clearer in the original question - the order of i is important as the values could be any data type which I believe precludes using `sorted`. I've updated the question.

Comment: That should be easy, just pass a "key function" to `sorted` that is based on `i` or `A` or whatever you call the super-list. I will update my answer.

Comment: Have you seen "lambda functions" before? Does it make sense what I am doing?

Comment: @PeacefulJames - great works perfectly thanks. Yes re the lambda - it is used to sort the outputs using the index order of the original list, very nice,

Comment: You said that the lists can be of any type, so I will provide a further example using a custom type. If this answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Changed to reflect that `j` is a list of the values to duplicate

```
for k in range(len(j) + 1):
    for n in itertools.combinations(j, k):
        lst = i[:]
        for el in n:
            ix = lst.index(el)
            lst.insert(ix, lst[ix])
        print(lst)
```

EDIT
using `insert` is more efficient than what I had before

Comment: @JBernando - sorry for not making it clearer that the j were a subset of the values in i. I've added a string example.

Comment: @geographika Ok so I fixed it to retrieve the indexes of values instead

Comment: works perfectly (and helped correct my manual output!)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
In [1]: %paste                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
from itertools import combinations

i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
j = [1, 4]

res = []
for r in range(len(j) + 1):
    for comb in combinations(j, r):
        res.append(sorted(i + list(comb)))
print(res)

## -- End pasted text --
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]]

In [2]:
```